# Python: codecs and utf-8 global error handling

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I need to setup a global error handling in `codecs` for third party package.

In my code I can do something like:

```
import codecs

print(
    codecs.encode('\ud83d', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
)
```

I want to achieve the same behavior globally. I am trying something like:

```
def relaxedutf8(exc):
    if not isinstance(exc, UnicodeDecodeError):
        raise TypeError("don't know how to handle %r" % exc)
    if exc.object[exc.start:exc.start+2] == "\xc0\x80":
        return (u"\x00", exc.start+2) # retry after two bytes
    else:
        raise exc

codecs.register_error("test.relaxedutf8", relaxedutf8)

print(
    codecs.encode('\ud83d', encoding='utf-8')
)
```

but it doesn't work. The error is:

```
  File "codecs_errros.py", line 18, in <module>
    codecs.encode('\ud83d', encoding='utf-8')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud83d' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

Comment: Is "\ud83d" the compelete source string?? Cause googling it propose u"\uD83D\uDE03" that is a smile face

Comment: It's from real user input. So, it's doesn't matter - i need to have a way to handle it

Comment: Note that `codecs.register_error` merely registers a new error handler that you could then pass to `encode` as `errors='test.relaxedutf8'`. Is there a particular reason you are reading the input with an external library? Does the library support reading as a binary string instead, which you could then manually decode, or could you make it output an encoding other than UTF-8 if it includes unpaired surrogates?

Comment: @user10186512 the reason you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640355/django-drf-utf-8-and-surrogates